# How do I log the state changes from SaltStack?

Tags: salt-stack

I have lots of servers (over 50) all getting their configuration from Salt Stack (and I love it so far). But all of that automation makes me worried a bit. If I schedule salt to run highstate on all servers every night, how can I ensure the changes are being applied correctly? Can I log the changes so that I can either review any changes to my servers daily or at least troubleshoot what salt magically changes over night?

Right now if I run salt '*' state.highstate on the master, I get many pages of output to the screen and then have to scroll a lot to find any changes. Also, this process is manual. I'd like something scheduled and automated.

Answer (score 1):

By default, data about jobs runs from the Salt is returned to the master.
Specifying returners will ensure that the data is *also* sent to the specified returner interfaces.

Specifying what returners to use is done when the command is invoked:

```
salt '*' test.ping --return smtp_return
```

It can be useful to include specific data to differentiate a job from other jobs. Take for example the schedule module. By using the metadata parameter a value can be associated with a scheduled job, although these metadata values aren't used in the execution of the job they can be used to search for specific job later.

```
job1:
  schedule.present:
    - function: state.apply
    - seconds: 1800
    - splay: 5
    - metadata:
        foo: bar
```

An example job search on the salt-master might look similar to this:

```
salt-run jobs.list_jobs search_metadata='{"foo": "bar"}'
```

Take a look at the [salt.runners.jobs](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/runners/all/salt.runners.jobs.html) and the [returners](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/returners/index.html) documentation for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility that I'm considering is to increase the [Log Level on the minion](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/configuration/minion.html#log-level) to info. Then use logstash to consume /var/log/salt/minion and use Elasticsearch or Kibana monitor changes to the logs.

Comment: Why not use a continuous integration tool like Jenkins for this purpose?

Comment: Using the [`Logstash Logging Handler`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/configuration/logging/handlers/salt.log.handlers.logstash_mod.html) you will be able to parse the salt logs to logstash directly.

Comment: I guess that processing this kind of logs are very dirty task and will not lead to the desired result